What are the latest safe methods for rooting Android 13 devices without tripping SafetyNet?
I'm considering rooting my Android 13 device to customize it further, but I want to ensure that I don’t lose access to apps that rely on SafetyNet or other security checks. Are there any updated guides, tools, or workarounds for achieving root while maintaining compatibility with banking apps, Google Pay, etc.? Any advice on Magisk modules or other tips would also be appreciated!

No matter what you do for rooting you need to unlock bootloader and that will trigger PlayIntegrityCheck. The only thing you can do is to fix the "bootloader hole" using modules like PlayIntegrityFix. However Google can update their Play services at any time so that the fix don't work anymore.

Maybe just keep two phones.
